# Setting program to be autorun through registry

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, autorun

I have the following code:
http://privatepaste.com/8364a2a7b8/12345

But it only writes "c" (supposedly, conversion to LPBYTE leaves one byte only).

What's the proper way to handle GetModuleFileName and registry edit?

Comment: This isn't a question. I think you can't come and say "Hey, fix my code!". What's the question here?

Comment: okay, what's the proper way to handle GetModuleFileName and registry edit? <- question.

Comment: the proper way to handle them is do what suppose to be done, and touch non other.

Answer (score 0):

```
strlen((char*)szPath2)+1
```

This is most likely where your problem is. I bet your program is compiled in UNICODE mode. `strlen` only works properly for ASCII strings. (The fact that you're having to cast from TCHAR to char is a big hint that something isn't right.)

To keep consistent with the usage of TCHAR and such, you should probably use `_tcslen` instead.